# How to pass a variable (file name) from an external php file to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

I have a file upload form in my .html file which runs a .php script. There, I create a unique file name that I need in my external javascript, so I can't copy the file name selected by the user, since it's not the file name saved on the server. I can't do an ajax request, since the php is run after submitting the file. The php has to be in a separate file, because the HTML has to stay a .html file. I tried setting the value of a hidden html-element to the file name, but this only seems to work if I change my HTML to a .php file.

Is there a solution to this unique problem? Can I somehow pass the value of the file name to an html-element and then read that value in my javascript? Or maybe even directly retrieve the name in javascript?

PHP-Code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('csv', 'png', 'jpg', 'pdf');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                //echo json_encode($fileDestination);
                //$('input:hidden#myPhpValue').val($fileDestination);
            } else {
                echo "Your file is too large";
            }
        } else {
            echo "There was an error with the upload";
        }
    } else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type";
    }
}
```

?>

HTML-form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
</form>
```

Thanks a lot,
Johannes

Comment: At the point where you have the commented out lines in your PHP you can return the URL, redirect the user (e.g. with a querystring containing the url) or render a new HTML document where they should land after they have submitted the form.

Comment: That form will make the browser upload the file, then navigate to `upload.php`, showing the output of that file in the browser. If the upload is successful, they will currently see nothing because upload.php doesn't output anything. How is this supposed to work, as in, what's the bigger picture here? Which HTML exactly needs that generated filename?

Comment: You could pass the value back to your HTML page using a header post to the html page to parse the string into the url the use a url query on your html page to get the value using javascript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Methods

Comment: Also you could absolutely upload the file via ajax, and have output.php echo just the filename, which can then be accessed in the ajax callback.

Comment: @ChrisG the echo's currently are just for me to see what's happening, the commented out lines were previous attempts of getting that name ($fileDestination). I need that name to access the uploaded and moved file in my javascript code to further process it (will only be a .csv in the end). How can I retrieve that echo from upload.php and not get redirected to upload.php, showing me the echo?

Comment: Two possibilities: add HTML to `upload.php` so it displays an actual page to the user and use any of the various methods to insert the filename (for instance `<script>const filename = "<?= $filename ?>";</script>` above your other script). Or do what I suggested in my previous comment and upload the file via ajax/fetch, then grab the filename from the reply, i.e. echo it and only it in upload.php)